# What frameworks / technologies to use in web applications for Real Time features?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, performance, elixir, real-time

**What do you recommend (or not) to use for Real Time features (like chats or auctions) in web applications?**

The most important for me is your **opinion** or **benchmarks** about the efficiency / performance / speed of specific frameworks, technologies and solutions.

For example:

- Ruby on Rails + ActionCable
- Phoenix + Elixir
- Socket.io

**QUESTION'S CONTEXT:**

Each framework, programming language, technology has some advantages and disadvantages which make it more or less effective for Real Time needs. Sometimes we can use multiple technologies to build app's backend, for example when backend is a set of cooperating services (SOA, micorservices, etc.). Due to both, we are able create some features in Ruby on Rails (because the implementation is fast) and other in Java (beacuse it works fast).

Comment: Take a look at these links which are alternatives to WebSockets and that explain advs & diadvts: [long polling](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/) (Facebook uses (or used, at least in the beginning) to retrieve the data). Also, [polling](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I would be on your side, I would follow Elixir & Phoenix path.

Elixir is basically Erlang with better syntax and it's open for extensions via macros, so you can customize it whatever you want.

Please take a look on these great articles about that:

[The road to 2 million websocket connections](http://www.phoenixframework.org/blog/the-road-to-2-million-websocket-connections)

[Phoenix Channels vs Rails Action Cable](https://dockyard.com/blog/2016/08/09/phoenix-channels-vs-rails-action-cable)

Basically:

Elixir was created to do handle such scenarios with grace, efficiency, low latency, great scalability and fun.

Ps. Please remember that the time of the compilation is not that important as time of handling the request / getting the response / handling multiple websocket connections.
Elixir is not the fasters language, but it leverages concurrency and it's unique in terms of responsiveness.

Comment: `s/better syntax/more familiar syntax/` :)